# Could not load file or assembly Xamarin.Interactive.iOS.dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I'm always getting this error and app crashes in ios.Android is working without any problem ,but in ios app crashes while loading.
I tried to restore nuget packages but still getting this error.Any help is appreciated ,thanks.

```
    InspectorDebugSession(1): StateChange: Start -> EntryPointBreakpointRegistered
InspectorDebugSession(1): Constructed
InspectorDebugSession(1): HandleTargetEvent: TargetReady
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/Xamarin.iOS.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.dll [External]
Resolved pending breakpoint for 'UIKit.UIApplication.Main(string[], string, string)' to /Users/builder/data/lanes/3985/ba11e481/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:61 [0x00000].
Resolved pending breakpoint for 'UIKit.UIApplication.Main(string[], System.Type, System.Type)' to /Users/builder/data/lanes/3985/ba11e481/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:68 [0x00000].
Resolved pending breakpoint for 'UIKit.UIApplication.Main(string[])' to /Users/builder/data/lanes/3985/ba11e481/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:73 [0x00000].
Resolved pending breakpoint for 'UIKit.UIApplication.Main(string[], System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr)' to /Users/builder/data/lanes/3985/ba11e481/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:78 [0x00000].
Thread started:  #2
InspectorDebugSession(1): HandleTargetEvent: ThreadStarted
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/pauxiOS.exe
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Runtime.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.ObjectModel.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/paux.dll
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Core.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Xml.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/Mono.Dynamic.Interpreter.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/Acr.UserDialogs.Interface.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/Splat.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Threading.Tasks.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Collections.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Text.Encoding.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Globalization.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.ComponentModel.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Reflection.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Linq.Expressions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.IO.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Dynamic.Runtime.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Threading.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Net.Http.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Runtime.Extensions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Linq.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Reflection.Extensions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/MvvmHelpers.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/Xamarin.Auth.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Net.Primitives.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/PCLCrypto.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/PInvoke.BCrypt.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/PInvoke.Windows.Core.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/PInvoke.Kernel32.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Numerics.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/Validation.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Net.Requests.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/Newtonsoft.Json.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Runtime.Numerics.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Xml.XmlDocument.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Xml.XDocument.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Xml.Linq.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Reflection.Primitives.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/Microsoft.CSharp.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/Mono.CSharp.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/Plugin.Settings.Abstractions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/Xamarin.Forms.Daddoon.IconTabbedPage.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Abstractions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/Acr.UserDialogs.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/Acr.Support.iOS.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/Plugin.Settings.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/Plugin.Connectivity.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/Plugin.Connectivity.Abstractions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/FFImageLoading.Forms.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/FFImageLoading.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/FFImageLoading.Platform.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/WebP.Touch.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/XLabs.Forms.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/XLabs.Core.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/XLabs.Platform.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/ExifLib.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/XLabs.Serialization.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/XLabs.Ioc.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/CarouselView.FormsPlugin.iOS.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Ext.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Net.Http.Primitives.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/paumac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F0ACDBD-B970-4269-BFA4-B7ADE7BEAFB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74FAFF6E-DE1F-46D6-B69C-D38BA1B73183/pauxiOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Linq.Queryable.dll [External]
InspectorDebugSession(1): HandleTargetEvent: TargetHitBreakpoint
InspectorDebugSession(1): StateChange: EntryPointBreakpointRegistered -> EntryPointBreakpointHit
InspectorDebugSession(1): AgentBridge.InjectAssembly: /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Interactive.framework/Versions/Current/Agents/iOS/Xamarin.Interactive.iOS.dll
InspectorDebugSession(1): HandleTargetEvent: ExceptionThrown
Exception:

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly '/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Interactive.framework/Versions/Current/Agents/iOS/Xamarin.Interactive.iOS.dll' or one of its dependencies

InspectorDebugSession(1): Disposed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the linker options ,(link behavior = link sdk assemblies only) And finally got a successfull build.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat orthogonal to your solution, but might help in debugging :-

To check if its a xamarin issue:

```
1: Check logs where all Xamarin.Interactive.iOS.dll is attempted to be loaded.
2: Search /Library folder for the missing dll. If dll is present, check why the dll is being loaded from a wrong path. You can try fiddling with 'Copy to Output Directory' property to get your dll dropped in correct path.
3: Restart the ios simulator.
4: Update SDK again
5: If the missing dll is not present on your system, perhaps your Xamarin installation is corrupted.
```

To check if its a build issue:

```
1: Check logs from Xamarin diagnostics.
2: Project properties > Enable debugging.
3: Clean solution > Rebuild.
```