# Xamarin - iOS. Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

When I try to debug iOS app I've got this:

Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.

I've tried to search some solutions, but they didn't work for me. When I start app without debugging it works. Android version works normally, I can debug it, only with iOS is a problem. I debug on the Windows, I'm paired with my Mac.

```
07:40:51.605 MyApp.iOS[2865:30981] Xamarin.iOS: Unable to locate assembly 
'Xamarin.Interactive' (culture: '')

 07:40:51.605 MyApp.iOS[2865:30981] Xamarin.iOS: Unable to locate assembly 
'Xamarin.Interactive' (culture: '')

 07:40:51.606 MyApp.iOS[2865:30981] Xamarin.iOS: Unable to locate assembly 'Xamarin.Interactive' (culture: '')

 07:40:51.606 MyApp.iOS[2865:30981] Xamarin.iOS: Unable to locate assembly 'Xamarin.Interactive' (culture: '')

 07:40:51.607 MyApp.iOS[2865:30981] critical: Stacktrace:

 07:40:51.608 MyApp.iOS[2865:30981] critical: 

Native stacktrace:


 07:40:51.610 MyApp.iOS[2865:30981] critical:   0   
MyApp.iOS                  0x000000010f195334 mono_handle_native_crash + 244
 07:40:51.610 MyApp.iOS[2865:30981] critical:   1   MyApp.iOS                  0x000000010f1a4960 mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 288
 07:40:51.611 MyApp.iOS[2865:30981] critical:   2   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x000000011fa5af5a _sigtramp + 26
 07:40:51.611 MyApp.iOS[2865:30981] critical:   3   ???                                 0x000000011b14b10b 0x0 + 4749308171
 07:40:51.611 MyApp.iOS[2865:30981] critical:   4   MyApp.iOS                  0x000000010f1d8b0f assembly_binding_info_parsed + 383
 07:40:51.611 MyApp.iOS[2865:30981] critical:   5   MyApp.iOS                  0x000000010f25c9ad assembly_binding_end + 61
 07:40:51.611 MyApp.iOS[2865:30981] critical:   6   MyApp.iOS                  0x000000010f25c2ca end_element + 42
 07:40:51.611 MyApp.iOS[2865:30981] critical:   7   MyApp.iOS                  0x000000010f343bff monoeg_g_markup_parse_context_parse + 479
 07:40:51.611 MyApp.iOS[2865:30981] critical:   8   MyApp.iOS                  0x000000010f25b4d4 mono_config_parse_xml_with_context + 180
 07:40:51.612 MyApp.iOS[2865:30981] critical:   9   MyApp.iOS                  0x000000010f25b790 mono_config_parse_file_with_context + 128
 07:40:51.612 MyApp.iOS[2865:30981] critical:   10  MyApp.iOS                  0x000000010f25ba09 mono_config_parse_assembly_bindings + 105
 07:40:51.612 MyApp.iOS[2865:30981] critical:   11  MyApp.iOS                  0x000000010f1d8962 mono_domain_parse_assembly_bindings + 114
 07:40:51.612 MyApp.iOS[2865:
30981] critical:    12  MyApp.iOS                  0x000000010f1d995b mono_assembly_load_full_nosearch + 2203
 07:40:51.612 MyApp.iOS[2865:30981] critical:   13  MyApp.iOS                  0x000000010f1d5688 mono_assembly_load_full_internal + 40
 07:40:51.612 MyApp.iOS[2865:30981] critical:   14  MyApp.iOS                  0x000000010f1d52d5 mono_assembly_load_reference + 517
 07:40:51.612 MyApp.iOS[2865:30981] critical:   15  MyApp.iOS                  0x000000010f1dc55d mono_class_from_typeref_checked + 733
 07:40:51.612 MyApp.iOS[2865:30981] critical:   16  MyApp.iOS                  0x000000010f1ea56e mono_class_get_checked + 174
 07:40:51.613 MyApp.iOS[2865:30981] critical:   17  MyApp.iOS                  0x000000010f1dca7b mono_class_create_from_typedef + 715
 07:40:51.613 MyApp.iOS[2865:30981] critical:   18  MyApp.iOS                 
 0x000000010f1ea51c mono_class_get_checked + 92
 07:40:51.613 MyApp.iOS[2865:30981] critical:   19  MyApp.iOS                  0x000000010f1eb20a mono_class_from_name_checked_aux + 986
 07:40:51.613 MyApp.iOS[2865:30981] critical:   20  MyApp.iOS                  0x000000010f1dc363 mono_class_from_typeref_checked + 227
 07:40:51.613 MyApp.iOS[2865:30981] critical:   21  MyApp.iOS                  0x000000010f1ea56e mono_class_get_checked + 174
 07:40:51.613 MyApp.iOS[2865:30981] critical:   22  MyApp.iOS                  0x000000010f24ea1b mono_metadata_parse_type_internal + 1419
 07:40:51.614 MyApp.iOS[2865:30981] critical:   23  MyApp.iOS                  0x000000010f1e0b1a mono_field_resolve_type + 586
 07:40:51.614 MyApp.iOS[2865:30981] critical:   24  MyApp.iOS                  0x000000010f1df923 mono_class_setup_fields + 467
 07:40:51
.614 MyApp.iOS[2865:30981] critical:    25  MyApp.iOS                  0x000000010f1e00ef mono_class_init + 463
 07:40:51.614 MyApp.iOS[2865:30981] critical:   26  MyApp.iOS                  0x000000010f2667b2 mono_class_vtable_full + 226
 07:40:51.614 MyApp.iOS[2865:30981] critical:   27  MyApp.iOS                  0x000000010f2688d7 mono_class_vtable + 23
 07:40:51.614 MyApp.iOS[2865:30981] critical:   28  MyApp.iOS                  0x000000010f0f681d type_commands_internal + 5197
 07:40:51.615 MyApp.iOS[2865:30981] critical:   29  MyApp.iOS                  0x000000010f0e8a86 debugger_thread + 2134
 07:40:51.615 MyApp.iOS[2865:30981] critical:   30  MyApp.iOS                  0x000000010f2b2390 start_wrapper + 704
 07:40:51.615 MyApp.iOS[2865:30981] critical:   31  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000011fa6c6c1 _pthread_body + 340
2
018-04-04 07:40:51.615 MyApp.iOS[2865:30981] critical:  32  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000011fa6c56d _pthread_body + 0
 07:40:51.615 MyApp.iOS[2865:30981] critical:   33  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000011fa6bc5d thread_start + 13
```

**Windows versions:**

VS Studio 2017 15.6.4
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 
Version 15.6.4
VisualStudio.15.Release/15.6.4+27428.2015
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.7.02556

=== Mono Debugging for Visual Studio ===

4.9.11-pre (71eb098)

=== Xamarin ===

4.9.0.752 (0faa808ee)

=== Xamarin Designer ===

4.10.58 (cee1369d0)

=== Xamarin.Android SDK ===

8.2.0.16 (HEAD/a78295902)

=== Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK ===

11.8.1.28 (3979d08)

**Mac:**

=== Visual Studio Community 2017 for Mac ===

Version 7.4.1 (build 48)
Installation UUID: 97bf3b32-4332-487e-8509-e2fd8ab64b1a
Runtime:
    Mono 5.8.1.0 (2017-10/6bf3922f3fd) (64-bit)
    GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)

```
Package version: 508010000
```

=== Xamarin.Profiler ===

Version: 1.6.1

=== Apple Developer Tools ===

Xcode 9.2 (13772)
Build 9C40b

=== Xamarin.Mac ===

Version: 4.2.1.28 (Visual Studio Community)

=== Xamarin.iOS ===

Version: 11.8.1.28 (Visual Studio Community)

=== Xamarin Inspector ===

Version: 1.4.0

Comment: When I put breakpoint in Main.cs file (from iOS project) debug works... when i disable it I can't debug app and I get error from above...

Comment: check the linker options in Properties , refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42945540/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-xamarin-interactive-ios-dll

Comment: Not working, i have new errors.